# Quiver plot changes when plotted on top of intensity

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, imshow

So I'm trying to plot a transverse vector field on top of an intensity plot.  If I just plot the vector field using the following code (with the intensity plot commented out)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import ma

X = np.loadtxt("X.csv", delimiter=",\t", skiprows=1)
Y = np.loadtxt("Y.csv", delimiter=",\t", skiprows=1)
Z = np.loadtxt("Z.csv", delimiter=",\t", skiprows=1)

U = X
V = Y

#plt.imshow(Z)
plt.quiver(U, V)
plt.show()
```

Everything works fine as seen in this plot.

**Correct Field**

[image: Correct Field]

However, if I run it and include the `plt.imshow(Z)` line, then it completely changes the vector field though it plots the intensity correctly.

**Incorrect Field**

[image: Incorrect Vector Field]

As you can see, the two fields are different.  Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two fields appear to be different because `imshow` modifies the default axis properties and reverses the direction of the y axis so instead of (0,0) being in the lower left it is in the upper left.

To correct this, you can use the `origin` parameter to `imshow`

```
plt.imshow(Z, origin='lower')
```

The other change is that `imshow` sets the data aspect ratio to be equal.